# How long does it take for Google to update change of address request?

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search-console

I have a real estate website with just forty important pages, and if tags get in way total index gets to 200 pages on Google. I 301 redirected all the pages to my new domain. It's been three days, and I can't post a new property because it won't rank on the new domain as it is still not finished transferring. How long will it take to get full transferred with all the site rankings?

Comment: What does `if tags get in way` mean? Did you follow all of the steps [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) (like verifying your site)? There's no set time (possibly a few weeks or more), and the positions in SERP aren't guaranteed to be the same (they might dip), but that shouldn't prevent you from adding new content and requesting it to be crawled with the Fetch as Google tool.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the requested clarification.